# XDocument Elements return null

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a xml and i am trying to get the elements of a particular xname 
so im trying to do something like...

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("C://some.xml");
XDocument subDoc = new XDocument(doc.Elements("data"));
```

but in subDoc no elements are returned, and i know i have a element named data, i have tried with the namespace too but not returning any element.

Im wonder if i can get a XDocument only with data (including) and his childs.

```
some.xml

<chart xmlns="http://www.somenamespace.com">
  <data>
    <table>
      <columns>
        <column id="001" label="A"/>
        <column id="002" label="B"/>
        <column id="003" label="C"/>
        <column id="004" label="D"/>
      </columns>
      <rows>
        <row>
          <cell>
            <float value="30"/>
          </cell>
          <cell>
            <float value="35"/>
          </cell>
          <cell>
            <float value="15"/>
          </cell>
          <cell>
            <float value="18"/>
          </cell>
        </row>
      </rows>
    </table>
  </data>
 <render />
</chart>
```

someone can Help?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the content of the _some.xml_ file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the System.Linq namespace directive to the top of your file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

And try this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("c:\\some.xml");
XName name = XName.Get("data", doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace().NamespaceName);
XDocument subDoc = new XDocument(doc.Descendants(name).First());
```

Comment: first not exist on descendands

Answer (score 1):

Your direct element node is probably not "data"...try descendants instead

```
doc.Descendants("data");
```

Comment: `data` is in another namespace, therefore it does not match any element.