# Why my code with XDocument in .NET not return any elements? (Problem with XML and XDocument)

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a problem with the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ReportName="SearchQueryPerformanceReport_05_24_2022_11_19_51" ReportTime="3/24/2022,5/23/2022" TimeZone="Various" ReportAggregation="Daily" LastCompletedAvailableDay="5/24/2022 10:20:00 AM (GMT)" LastCompletedAvailableHour="5/24/2022 10:20:00 AM (GMT)" PotentialIncompleteData="true" xmlns="http://adcenter.microsoft.com/advertiser/reporting/v5/XMLSchema">
  <Table>
    <Row>
      <AccountName value="fffffff" />
      <CampaignName value="dddddddddddddd" />
      <CampaignId value="424769594" />
      <Clicks value="1" />
      <CostPerConversion value="" />
      <Ctr value="100.00%" />
      <AccountId value="1848" />
      <DeviceType value="Computer" />
      <AverageCpc value="0.25" />
      <AveragePosition value="0.00" />
      <BidMatchType value="Exact" />
      <AdGroupName value="eeeeeeeeee" />
      <AdGroupId value="135899347066" />
      <AdId value="84933705" />
      <ConversionRate value="0.00%" />
      <Keyword value="zusammen at" />
      <KeywordId value="84937818" />
      <Language value="German" />
      <Conversions value="0" />
      <Impressions value="1" />
      <Spend value="0.25" />
      <TimePeriod value="2022-04-13" />
      <SearchQuery value="zusammen.at" />
    </Row>
  </Table>
  <Copyright>©2022 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. </Copyright>
</Report>
```

When I use this code the XML does not return any element.

`XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(LstSearchTermV.XmlContent); var result2 = from s in doc.Descendants("Table");`

or

`var result2 = from s in doc.Element("Table");`

or

`var result2 = from s in doc.Elements("Row");`

I have tried different ways but nothing.

I test  with other XML and have same problem.

Does anyone know why, where is the problem?

Update:
I try it: [XDocument Elements return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427930/xdocument-elements-return-null)

It work and I get elements but, when I try to get values is very long code, example:
`var ValueElement = el.Element(XName.Get("CampaignId", doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace().NamespaceName)).Attributes().Where(w => w.Name == "value");`

¿Is any code more short or more optimized to get data of XDocument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely write simpler code than that, using the `XNamespace` type and the various operators and conversions available to create an `XName`, and using the `Attribute` method that looks for an attribute with a given name:

```cs
// Or XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace()
XNamespace ns = "http://adcenter.microsoft.com/advertiser/reporting/v5/XMLSchema";
var value = el.Element(ns + "CampaignId").Attribute("value");
```

`value` will be null if there's no such attribute.